# PayPal IPN doesn't reach EC2 tomcat

Tags: paypal, amazon-ec2, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to get IPN to my site, hosted on Amazon AWS EC2. The web server is Tomcat 7. Using PayPal sandbox.

The site has a Servlet or JSP to get the request.

When I set the IPN URL to my local machine (using IP address) it works, but setting it to the public site doesn't. 
It doesn't matter if use site name or IP address, servlet or JSP.

In the access log I don't see any request for the IPN URL.

IPN Simulator with the IPN URL works.

in AWS ports 80 and 443 are opened for all IP range (0.0.0.0/0).

I think I checked everything, so I'm totally lost right now.

Comment: Are you getting an error on the script at all? Have you checked the IPN History for the account receiving the post?

Comment: After further investigation I found out that IPN requests from PayPal do get to the server (I see them in TCPDUMP), however they don't get to Tomcat (don't see them in the access log). 

It looks to me like a n SSL Certificate issue, because when I simulate the request from IPN Simulator or Fiddler, I see certificate related text in the TCPDUMP content, but I don't see it when the requests come from Sandbox.

I use SSL with GoDaddy certificate. Anything special related to SSL Certificates I need to do in order to enable the IPN requests to my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved after installing Linux updates and restarting the server. I don't know why, but SSL certificate did not work correctly before the updates and/or reboot